# LPSTREAM unable to read into CString

Tags: c++, stream, storage, compound-file

I'm attempting to read text into a CString using an LPSTREAM, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, here is the code that I'm calling:

```
static HRESULT UTL_ReadStreamTxt(MyStorage* pSrcStg, const char* pszStream, CString* myCStr, int size)
{
        HRESULT     hrRet = STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER;
        LPSTREAM    lpSrc = NULL;
        ULONG ul;

        TRY
        { 
            USES_CONVERSION;
            HRESULT hrSrc = pSrcStg->GetStg()->OpenStream(CT2COLE(strSrc),          
                                                    NULL,
                                                    STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
                                                    0,
                                                    &lpSrc);
            if (hrSrc != NOERROR)
            {
                hrRet = hrSrc;
            }
            else
            {
                hrRet = lpSrc->Read(&myCStr, size, NULL); // Read into CString
            }

        }

        CATCH_ALL(e)
        {
            hrRet = STG_E_UNKNOWN;
        }
        END_CATCH_ALL


        _AfxRelease((LPUNKNOWN*)&lpSrc);

        return hrRet;
}
```

When it reads into the string, Visual Studio says that the data in the CString is corrupted.

The compound storage's stream contents are the following:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I'm not entirely sure I'm using Read() correctly, How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `ULONG read = 0; hrRet = lpSrc->Read(myCStr->GetBuffer(size), size, &read); myCStr->ReleaseBuffer(read);` Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are passing a bad pointer to `Read()`.  You are passing the memory address of the `myCStr` parameter itself, not the address of the `CString` being pointed at, or more accurately, the memory address of a character buffer that the `CString` owns.  The code compiles only because `Read()` takes a simple `void*` pointer to a buffer, and *any* pointer is implicitly convertible to `void*`.

Also note that `CString` is based on `TCHAR`, which maps to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether you are compiling your project for ANSI/MBCS or Unicode.  So, reading from the stream directly into a `CString` will only work correctly if:

1. the stream contains ANSI characters and `TCHAR` maps to `char`.
2. the stream contains UTF-16 characters and `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`.

If the stream's character type does not match the character type used by `CString`, you would have to first read the stream into an intermediate buffer and then convert that to `TCHAR` before it can be stored in the `CString`.

Try something more like this:

```
static HRESULT UTL_ReadStreamTxt(MyStorage* pSrcStg, const char* pszStream, CString* myCStr, int size)
{
    HRESULT     hrRet = STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER;
    LPSTREAM    lpSrc = NULL;
    ULONG       ul;
    LPVOID      buffer;

    TRY
    { 
        USES_CONVERSION;
        HRESULT hrSrc = pSrcStg->GetStg()->OpenStream(CT2COLE(strSrc),          
                                                    NULL,
                                                    STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
                                                    0,
                                                    &lpSrc);
        if (hrSrc != S_OK)
        {
            hrRet = hrSrc;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the stream's character type matches TCHAR...

            buffer = myCStr->GetBuffer(size / sizeof(TCHAR));
            hrRet = lpSrc->Read(buffer, size, &ul);
            myCStr->ReleaseBuffer(ul / sizeof(TCHAR));

            // else, if the stream's character type is 'char' and TCHAR is 'wchar_t'...

            CStringA tmp;
            buffer = tmp.GetBuffer(size);
            hrRet = lpSrc->Read(buffer, size, &ul);
            tmp.ReleaseBuffer(ul);
            *myCStr = CString((LPSTR)tmp, tmp.GetLength());

            // else, if the stream's character type is 'wchar_t' and TCHAR is 'char'...

            CStringW tmp;
            buffer = tmp.GetBuffer(size / sizeof(wchar_t));
            hrRet = lpSrc->Read(buffer, size, &ul);
            tmp.ReleaseBuffer(ul / sizeof(wchar_t));
            *myCStr = CString((LPWSTR)tmp, tmp.GetLength());

            // alternatively, you can do the above 2 cases more generically...

            typedef CStringT<char or wchar_t> CStreamString;
            CStreamString tmp;
            buffer = tmp.GetBuffer(size / sizeof(CStreamString::XCHAR));
            hrRet = lpSrc->Read(buffer, size, &ul);
            tmp.ReleaseBuffer(ul / sizeof(CStreamString::XCHAR));
            *myCStr = CString((CStreamString::PXSTR)tmp, tmp.GetLength());
        }
    }

    CATCH_ALL(e)
    {
        hrRet = STG_E_UNKNOWN;
    }
    END_CATCH_ALL

    _AfxRelease((LPUNKNOWN*)&lpSrc);

    return hrRet;
}
```